# How do I create test plans using Microsoft Test Manager / Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate? They keep on being removed on creation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

One of my colleagues is facing an issue with creating a test plan using Microsoft Test Manager 2010. We are using TFS 2010 and Visual Studio Ultimate. He is able to successfully "create" the test plan, but as soon as he is done, the test plan is removed. If he refreshes, then the test plan disappears and if he attempts to click on it, he gets the following error -

### The test plan has been removed

The test plan you tried to connect to has been removed, please select another plan to connect to.

I made sure he has the correct access rights to Manage Test Plans within the Areas and Iterations security. One thing that concerns me, however, is if I try to see the ACL for this from TfsSecurity.exe, nothing comes up. I have made sure the URI of the project is accurate as well. The command I am using is:

```
tfssecurity /acl CSS
--> $PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/11ebab88-2892-4c85-b650-83720f194c21
--> /Collection:[our collection address]
```

No results are returned from this command, which concerns me because I am able to see some security settings for the Area level from within Visual Studio.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Please inspect the TFS server logs for any errors

Comment: I figured it out. The "Manage Test Plans" permission is not enough to see the test plans, although it is enough to create them. The result is then that you can create a plan, but not see the plan YOU created. Kind of counter-intuitive, IMHO. You need the "View this Node" permission to see the test plans.

Comment: Nice! Those things are always hard to figure out!

Comment: @Nick: you should create an answer with the successful information. This would make it easier to find for others with the same problem. I would then gladly upvote the answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks for the tip. I actually tried to do that as soon as I found the answer out, but my reputation was < 100, and so StackOverflow wouldn't let me for at least 8 hrs after the post. And, then I never got back to it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out - you need both 'Manage Test Plans' and 'View this Node' in order to actually manage the test plans. Only having one of the rights will either allow you to create new test plans or view existing test plans, depending on which right you have. The combination of the two allows you to create, edit, view, and delete test plans.

It is kind of counter-intuitive, especially since the description of the 'View this node' right is "Users who have this permission can view the security settings for this node."

The "View this Node" permission in TFS 2010 has changed to "View permissions for this node" in TFS 2012.

Comment: This worked for me in TFS 2012, had to set both permissions in "Areas" permissions settings !